# How to load data from cassandra into NIFI

Tags: cassandra, minify, apache-nifi

I want to use the querycassandra processor, but i'm facing some troubles. I'm trying to do some very basic actions which is selecting all rows from a table and then send them to another ExcecuteStream processor(java program).

Here is the table :
[image]

Here is the processor configuration. I've also added the port 9042 to the HDP sandbox both from the port forwarding table and the start_sandbox script:

[image]

username/password: cassandra

[image]

a global schema showing the error:

all host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:[/127.0.0.1] Cannot connect)

[image]

Comment: Can you connect to that service on the command line using [`cqlsh`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html)? Have you tried using `localhost:9042` as the contact point?

Comment: Hi @Andy, yes, from my linux host, but HDP here is in the sandbox on vm, i'm wondering if they are able to communicate or do i need to install cassandra in my sandbox host too..